# Unable to move goal gizmo in rviz MoveIt demo

Tags: urdf, moveit, ros-melodic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a MoveIt config with the setup wizard from my URDF. Why trying out the demo.launch I can plan to random goal positions, but I cannot specify goal positions manually by moving the gizmos. With earlier versions of the URDF, I was only to able to rotate the gizmos along the wrist axis. How do I need to specify my arm such that I can select goals to plan to freely?

The robot arm is a SCARA version, here my URDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="rrbot" 
  xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- Constants for robot dimensions -->
  <xacro:property name="pole_offset" value="0.2" />
  <xacro:property name="pole_length" value="3" />
  <xacro:property name="pole_radius" value="0.05" />

  <xacro:property name="width1" value="0.1" />
  <xacro:property name="width2" value="0.1" />
  <xacro:property name="width3" value="0.1" />
  <xacro:property name="length1" value="-0.3" />
  <xacro:property name="length2" value="-0.7" />
  <xacro:property name="length3" value="-0.7" />

  <xacro:property name="overlap_1_2" value="0.1" />
  <xacro:property name="overlap_2_3" value="0.1" />

  <xacro:property name="pi_rad" value="3.14" />

  <!-- world link -->
  <link name="world"/>

  <!-- base_link and its fixed joint -->
  <joint name="joint_fix" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="sbase_link"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="sbase_link">
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 ${pole_offset}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${pole_length}" radius="${pole_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 ${pole_offset}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${pole_length}" radius="${pole_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 ${pole_offset}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <xacro:macro name="box_arm" params="name parent width length *origin">
    <joint name="${name}_rotation" type="revolute">
      <!-- <origin xyz="0 ${pole_radius + y + overlap_1_2} ${-0.5 * y}" rpy="0 0 0"/> -->
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin" />
      <parent link="${parent}"/>
      <child link="${name}_link"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <limit effort="1000" velocity="1000" lower="${-0.5* pi_rad}" upper="${0.5*pi_rad}"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="${name}_link">
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 ${0.5 * length} ${-0.5 * width}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="${width} ${length} ${width}"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 ${0.5 * length} ${-0.5 * width}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="${width} ${length} ${width}"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>

      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0 ${0.5 * length} ${-0.5 * width}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="1"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.001" iyz="0.0" izz="0.001"/>
      </inertial>
    </link>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="scara_arm" params="name min_z max_z pole_radius
                                        width1 width2 width3 
                                        length1 length2 length3
                                        overlap_1_2 overlap_2_3">
    <joint name="${name}_prismatic" type="prismatic">
      <parent link="sbase_link"/>
      <child link="${name}_part1_link"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <limit effort="1000" velocity="1000" lower="${min_z}" upper="${max_z}"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="${name}_part1_link">
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 ${pole_radius + 0.5*length1} 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="${width1} ${length1} ${width1}"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 ${pole_radius + 0.5*length1} 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="${width1} ${length1} ${width1}"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>

      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0 ${pole_radius + 0.5*length1} 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="1"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.001" iyz="0.0" izz="0.001"/>
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <xacro:box_arm name="${name}_part2" parent="${name}_part1_link" width="${width2}" length="${length2}">
      <origin xyz="0 ${pole_radius + length1 + overlap_1_2} ${-0.5 * width1}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:box_arm>

    <xacro:box_arm name="${name}_part3" parent="${name}_part2_link" width="${width3}" length="${length3}">
      <origin xyz="0 ${length2 + overlap_2_3} ${-1* width2}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:box_arm>

    <joint name="wrist_joint" type="">
      <origin xyz="0 ${length3} -${width3/2}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="${name}_part3_link"/>
      <child link="wrist_link"/>
      <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
      <limit lower="0.0" upper="3.141" effort="0.1" velocity="1"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="wrist_link">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0.8 0"/>
        <mass value="0.1"/>
        <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0.8 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.12 0.01 0.12"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0.8 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.12 0.01 0.12"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>

    <joint name="ee_joint" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="wrist_link"/>
      <child link="ee_link"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <limit lower="0.0" upper="0.0" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="ee_link">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="0.1"/>
        <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" 
                iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" 
                izz="1.0"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <sphere radius="${width3/2}"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <sphere radius="${width3/2}"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:scara_arm name="arm1" 
    min_z="${pole_offset - pole_length/2}" max_z="${pole_offset + pole_length/2}" 
    pole_radius="${pole_radius}"
    width1="${width1}" width2="${width2}" width3="${width3}"
    length1="${length1}" length2="${length2}" length3="${length3}"
    overlap_1_2="${overlap_1_2}" overlap_2_3="${overlap_2_3}"
  />
</robot>
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340050/unable-to-move-goal-gizmo-in-rviz-moveit-demo/) by [Saduras](https://answers.ros.org/users/50318/saduras/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2019-12-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-16**:\

> but I cannot specify goal positions manually by moving the gizmos

the "gizmos" are called *[interactive markers](http://wiki.ros.org/interactive_markers)* :)

> The robot arm is a SCARA version

the IM may not work as a SCARA is typically a 4dof robot. The default KDL IK solver does not work very well with such kinematic configurations. As the IM relies on the IK solver working, you cannot drag it around like you'd do with a 6 dof robot.

You may need to select *Allow Approximate Solutions* in the MoveIt RViz planning plugin, or generate a custom IK plugin for your 4dof robot.

**Comment by [Aradra](https://answers.ros.org/users/38611/aradra/) on 2019-12-16**:
So MoveIt dosent solve robot with less than 6 DOF ?
To do custom IK Plugin he has to do inverse kinematics from scratch also what about joint velocity ? Does he have to compute jacobian ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-16**:\

> So MoveIt dosent solve robot with less than 6 DOF ?

please read carefully: KDL does not work with 4 dof robots very well.

I did not say anything about MoveIt. MoveIt doesn't care. It works with 1 dof to `N` dof robots. As long as you have a working IK solver it can use it (or actually: if you want to be able to specify Pose goals, you'll need an IK solver. For jointspace goals you would not need one).

> To do custom IK Plugin he has to do inverse kinematics from scratch

Or use something like [ikfast](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/index.html).

> what about joint velocity ? Does he have to compute jacobian ?

MoveIt (or really: OMPL) does not do anything with velocities. I'm not sure what you're referring to here.

**Comment by [Aradra](https://answers.ros.org/users/38611/aradra/) on 2019-12-16**:
Sorry for getting it wrong.
Thank you for the detailed explanation

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-16**:
There is no need to apologise. I just wanted to make sure you understood things correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the solution myself: I had to change the wrist joint to revolute with rotation axis (0,1,0). I guess without it it does have not enough DoF to move the end-effector within the x-y plane with arbitrary rotations. Guess this is required to move the goal position freely in x-y.

---

Originally posted by [Saduras](https://answers.ros.org/users/50318/saduras/) with karma: 36 on 2019-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0